# Multiplying three matrices in BLAS with the middle one being diagonal

Tags: c, matrix-multiplication, blas

`A` is an `MxK` matrix, `B` is a vector of size `K`, and `C` is a `KxN` matrix. What set of BLAS operators should I use to compute the matrix below?

```
M = A*diag(B)*C
```

One way to implement this would be using three for loops like below

```
for (int i=0; i<M; ++i)
    for (int j=0; j<N; ++j)
        for (int k=0; k<K; ++k)
            M(i,j) = A(i,k)*B(k)*C(k,j);
```

Is it actually worth implementing this in BLAS in order to gain better speed efficiency?

Comment: Is it worth it? How big are your matrices?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First compute `D = diag(B)*C`, then use the appropriate BLAS matrix-multiply to compute `A*D`.

You can implement `diag(B)*C` using a loop over elements of `B` and calling to the appropriate BLAS scalar-multiplication routine.

Comment: There's no optimised routine for matrix-matrix and matrix-vector multiplication when one of the matrices is diagonal? That's incredible.

Comment: See also this answer which points to the *?sbmv* functions, for working with band matrices such as diagonal matrices. From the sound of it though it's unlikely to give good performance. https://stackoverflow.com/a/13433038/