# Element-wise vector-vector multiplication in BLAS?

Tags: c++, blas

Is there a means to do element-wise vector-vector multiplication with BLAS, GSL or any other high performance library ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I found that MKL has a whole set of mathematical operations on vector, in its Vector Mathematical Functions Library (VML), including v?Mul, which does what I want. It works with c++ arrays, so it's more convenient for me than GSL.

Answer (score 18):

(Taking the title of the question literally...)

Yes it can be done with BLAS alone (though it is probably not the most efficient way.)

The trick is to treat one of the input vectors as a diagonal matrix:

```
⎡a    ⎤ ⎡x⎤    ⎡ax⎤
⎢  b  ⎥ ⎢y⎥ =  ⎢by⎥
⎣    c⎦ ⎣z⎦    ⎣cz⎦
```

You can then use one of the matrix-vector multiply functions that can take a diagonal matrix as input without padding, e.g. [`SBMV`](http://www.netlib.org/blas/dsbmv.f)

Example:

```
void ebeMultiply(const int n, const double *a, const double *x, double *y)
{
    extern void dsbmv_(const char *uplo,
                       const int *n,
                       const int *k,
                       const double *alpha,
                       const double *a,
                       const int *lda,
                       const double *x,
                       const int *incx,
                       const double *beta,
                       double *y,
                       const int *incy);

    static const int k = 0; // Just the diagonal; 0 super-diagonal bands
    static const double alpha = 1.0;
    static const int lda = 1;
    static const int incx = 1;
    static const double beta = 0.0;
    static const int incy = 1;

    dsbmv_("L", &n, &k, &alpha, a, &lda, x, &incx, &beta, y, &incy);
}

// Test
#define N 3
static const double a[N] = {1,3,5};
static const double b[N] = {1,10,100};
static double c[N];

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    ebeMultiply(N, a, b, c);
    printf("Result: [%f %f %f]\n", c[0], c[1], c[2]);
    return 0;
}
```

`Result: [1.000000 30.000000 500.000000]`

Comment: I know this is fairly late, but I just wanna say that although this answer by finnw is a valid one, I probaby don't recommend using it. In my practical cases just writing loops myself was much faster (2-3 times). I don't know how much my compiler optimizes, but usually switching to blas yields a good speedup (e.g. 2-3 times in the other direction) instead of slowing down. Of course this depends on several factors, but just as a warning to time the calculations.

Comment: I can confirm @oli's findings. For me, ssbmv with N = 300 was ~20× slower than two nested for loops. I am using Intel Xeon X7560, OpenBLAS, and GCC 8.3.0 with the `-O2 -fPIC -fstack-protector-strong` options. My guess is that ?sbmv are too general and fail to make optimal use of vectorized instructions.

Answer (score 9):

There is always std::valarray<sup>1</sup>  which defines elementwise operations that are frequently (Intel C++ `/Quse-intel-optimized-headers`, G++) compiled into SIMD instructions if the target supports them.

- http://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/hpc/composerxe/en-us/cpp/mac/cref_cls/common/cppref_valarray_intro.htm

Both these compilers will also do auto-vectorization

- http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/getting-code-ready-for-parallel-execution-with-intel-parallel-composer/
- http://gcc.gnu.org/projects/tree-ssa/vectorization.html

In that case you can just write

```
#define N 10000 

float a[N], b[N], c[N]; 

void f1() { 
  for (int i = 1; i < N; i++) 
  c[i] = a[i] + b[i]; 
}
```

and see it compile into vectorized code (using SSE4 e.g.)

<sup>1</sup> Yes they are archaic and often thought of as obsolete, but in practice they are both standard and fit the task very well.

Comment: It seems that your first link is dead.

Answer (score 5):

In GSL, `gsl_vector_mul` does the trick.