# Element wise multiplication between matrices in BLAS?

Tags: c++, matlab, matrix, blas

I'm starting to use BLAS functions in c++ (specifically Intel MKL) to create faster versions of some of my old Matlab code.

It's been working out well so far, but I can't figure out how to perform elementwise multiplication on 2 matrices (A .* B in Matlab).

I know gemv does something similar between a matrix and a vector, so should I just break one of my matrices into vectors and call gemv repeatedly? I think this would work, but I feel like there should be something built in for this operation.

---

Comment: Not sure BLAS supports this. Maybe [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7621520/element-wise-vector-vector-multiplication-in-blas) is related if you can just treat the matrix data as linear. See also [this thread](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/294825).

Comment: Support for this was apparently added to MKLDNN, but I don't think MKL itself supports it directly. I don't have a code-fragment showing how it's used. https://github.com/oneapi-src/oneDNN/issues/255

Answer (score 3):

Use the Hadamard product. In MKL it's [v?MUL](https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/470448). E.g. for doubles:

```
vdMul( n, a, b, y );
```

in Matlab notation it performs:

```
y[1:n] = a[1:n] .* b[1:n]
```

In your case you can treat matrices as vectors.

Comment: Here is the same link for c++ reference
https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/521769

Comment: The links have rotted, here's the updated address: https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/documentation/onemkl-developer-reference-c/top/vector-mathematical-functions/vm-mathematical-functions/arithmetic-functions/v-mul.html