# Is there a name for this matrix operator $\odot$?

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra, matrix-multiplication, algebra

Box II shows the definition of a matrix operator, denoted $\odot$. Is there a name for it?
[image]

**Update**: I found it, "face-splitting product". See also https://www.slyusar.kiev.ua/FACE.pdf

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not a programming question.

Answer (score 0):

That's the Hadamard product, it seems not available in BLAS, but you can get it using the trick pointed out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7621520/)